# C++11 File Streams

Tags: c++, filestream, c++11, move-semantics

Has C++11 move semantics made the use of `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` easier or safer with regards to exceptions? I guess it depends on the standard library aswell. Any differences there between GCC, ICC and VC++ Compiler?

Comment: In what way are they not exception safe?

Comment: And how would move semantics affect exception safety in any case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The exception safety aspects of the std::stream classes has not been impacted.  The only difference is that you can now return streams from factory functions and store them in containers.